Tool for plotting spin texture
Is there a tool that can plot a spin texture graph like these two examples below:


Or does anyone know an example using matplotlib?

If you are okay with a 2D graph using matplotlib, I have already written an answer here, which is also the accepted answer by the OP.
https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/11458/6687

Cool question. I use Mayavi for volumetric plots only, but I know it can do stuff like this. However, I find it kinda hard to use and even harder to install and get working on Ubuntu 18.04/22.04.
I will probably switch to PyVista when I get a time to learn it. It seems easier to install and use. It can definitely make plots like that! See this example. With a little effort, I am sure you can adapt it to your needs!

In addition to what Tyler suggested, the open source ParaView can also create such plots. The learning curve is somewhat steep, but as a 3D visualization software it's very powerful and IMHO worths the effort. Here's an example I found at https://dataviz.shef.ac.uk/blog/05/10/2021/Paraview:

You also have to export your data into a suitable format, such as VTK - I usually use the pyevtk Python library for this.
